# What are vertical scalability limits of JFrog Artifactory Pro?

Tags: artifactory, high-availability, operations

The essential feature of JFrog Enterprise over JFrog Pro (X) is that it introduces high availability and site replication support.

Obviously, operations in geographically distributed organizations with thousands developers and build processes require some planning also for this aspect.

Nevertheless, is there any data/study to show order of magnitude of load where you would say okay this is where we need not just some vertical scaling but parallel (say using some reference hardware setup)?

Comment: Since the limits of vertical scaling are usually based on what sort of hardware you can get (or your hosting provider will give you), this will be highly dependent on your hosting situation, no?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov say there is some reference setup so that comparison makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As @XiongChiamiov mentioned, it's a very hard question to answer, but here's a clue:

Artifactory is a network-bond server. It means given enough storage, CPU and memory, it will max out your network interface first. Network interface is considered maxed out at half its rated bandwidth limitation. That can help you do the math.